# Cesium - TypeError : t is undefined when Focusing Camera on Object

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I've loaded some JSon data outlining each country on a globe as a `GeoJSonDataSource` into my Cesium project.  Each country is also copied as a separate entry into an array.  In order to highlight a country, I use

`viewer.entities.add(countryArray[countryID]);`

which places a colored polygon over the selected country when the user clicks on it.  However, when I click on the Camera icon in the info box that Cesium provides by default, nothing happens.  In the console, the error message reads:

> TypeError: t is undefined

and points to Cesium.js.  If I don't add anything to the `viewer.entities` array, this error doesn't appear.

Comment: Can you give an example of a value used for countryID in the code above?

Comment: @DerekK They're strings that use the 3-letter country codes, followed by a number for countries with multiple separate pieces.  For example, USA_2, or AFG.

Comment: Typically if you're accessing a stored item by a string you would want to use an object rather than an array. Depending on how your array is built `countryArray[countryID]` may return undefined. I am wondering if that may be what is happening here.

Comment: @DerekK, thanks, but the problem wasn't accessing the array.  Array may have been the wrong word, but in Javascript I usually use "Array"s and "Hashmap"s interchangeably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way to highlight the selected country.  Try capturing the selected entity, and change the material properties on the existing polygon, rather than creating a new one.

For example, give this a try:  Load up the [Cesium Sandcastle](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Hello%20World.html&label=Showcases) and paste in the following code into the code editor, then hit F8:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    navigationHelpButton: false, animation: false, timeline: false,
    selectionIndicator: false
});

var deselectColor = Cesium.Color.BLUE.withAlpha(0.3);
var selectedColor = Cesium.Color.LIME.withAlpha(0.5);

var deselectMaterial = new Cesium.ColorMaterialProperty(
        new Cesium.ConstantProperty(deselectColor));
var selectedMaterial = new Cesium.ColorMaterialProperty(
        new Cesium.ConstantProperty(selectedColor));

viewer.dataSources.add(Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load(
        '../../SampleData/ne_10m_us_states.topojson', {
    stroke: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
    fill: deselectColor,
    strokeWidth: 2
}));

//Set the camera to a US centered tilted view.
viewer.camera.lookAt(Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-98.0, 40.0),
        new Cesium.Cartesian3(0.0, -4790000.0, 3930000.0));
viewer.camera.lookAtTransform(Cesium.Matrix4.IDENTITY);

var previousEntity;
Cesium.knockout.getObservable(viewer, '_selectedEntity').subscribe(function(newEntity) {
    if (Cesium.defined(previousEntity) && Cesium.defined(previousEntity.polygon)) {
        previousEntity.polygon.material = deselectMaterial;
    }
    if (Cesium.defined(newEntity) && Cesium.defined(newEntity.polygon)) {
        newEntity.polygon.material = selectedMaterial;
    }
    previousEntity = newEntity;
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  After a small modification, that worked perfectly.  With your example, it only highlighted the single entity that was clicked on, which is a problem for countries like America or Canada that have separate bits of land.  I had it make an array of every piece with the same name as the selected entity, so that it now highlights the entire country.